# use of Bar Button item on Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to implement the Bar Button item on navigation bar,using that Bar Button item i want to navigate to another page,As i am new to iphone development,seek your help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnAction)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButton];
    [rightBarButton release];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
UIButton *btnPrev =[[UIButton alloc] init];
    [btnPrev setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnPrevious.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnPrev.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 30);
    [btnPrev addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    UIBarButtonItem *btnBack =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnPrev];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnBack;
```